# What to do with Fragments when they are dismissed (not visible)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am rewriting a Bluetooth app with 3 Activities to use just 1 Activity and 3 Fragments:

[image: diagram]

So I have now 4 files:

- **MainActivity.java** (contains bluetooth and shared preferences code)
- **MainFragment.java** (contains ellipsis menu to show SettingsFragment)
- **SettingsFragment.java** (contains "scan" button to show ScanningFragment)
- **ScanningFragment.java** (displays nearby bluetooth devices in a list)

It almost works, but as an Android programming newbie I don't understand - what to do with Fragments when I show some other Fragment?

Should I just drop the Fragments (and remove from FragmentManager?) to be garbage collected?

Or should I add these 3 private variables to **MainActivity.java** and reuse them (when the user navigates forwards and backwards)?

```
private MainFragment mMainFragment;
private SettingsFragment mSettingsFragment;
private ScanningFragment mScanningFragment;
```

Or does [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) somehow manage all 3 Fragment for me - regardless if they are visible or not?

Here is my current code (it is simple, I just call `replace()` all the time)-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
                                            MainListener, 
                                            SettingsListener, 
                                            ScanningListener,
                                            BleWrapperUiCallbacks {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // empty FrameLayout

        Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "main")
            .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Fragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "settings")
                    .commit();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // implementing SettingsFragment.SettingsListener interface

    public void scanClicked() {
        // TODO how to stop indicator when returned?
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        String address = // get from shared preferences
        Fragment fragment = ScanningFragment.newInstance(address);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "scan")
            .commit();
    }
```

Comment: depends on your need. If you want to have in  backstack for later use then Yes, if not then No.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: Using the `replace()` transaction causes the relevant fragment to be replaced and unreferenced, though if you add the transaction to the back stack, the manager will take care of reverting it for you on the back key being pressed. If you wish to retain the fragment instances, then you should use the `attach()` and `detach()` transactions instead, which just removes it from the UI, but causes the instance to be retained and reused by the manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I just drop the Fragments (and remove from FragmentManager?) to
>   be garbage collected?

No need to do anything else. FragmentManager is the guy in charge of Fragments' lifecycle. Once you call `replace()`, FragmentManager takes care for the rest. If needed it will keep fragment in memory, or release it.

> Or should I add these 3 private variables to MainActivity.java and
>   reuse them (when the user navigates forwards and backwards)?

No, don't do it because of the said above.

> Or does FragmentManager somehow manage all 3 Fragment for me -
>   regardless if they are visible or not?

Yes, it does. For instance, if you have invisible retained fragment, it's enough to create it once, and FragmentManager will take care of it and will keep it even when activity gets re-created during configuration change.

If you create fragments dynamically (as far as I can see, this is your case) then I suggest to add very first fragment dynamically too. You can do it like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // empty FrameLayout

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {  // <- important
        Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "main")
            .commit();
    }
}
```

This will ensure you don't duplicate MainFragment on configuration change, because when `savedInstanceState` is not null, then FragmentManager keeps instance of your fragment already.

Comment: Okay, you say the FragmentManager will keep the Fragment in memory if needed. Can I reuse it then and how? For example when moving from SettingsFragment to ScanningFragment (to select a Bluetooth device from the list) and then back to SettingsFragment.

Comment: You do the same you did for settings fragment (replace() and addToBackStack()). Once done, back button should works properly. If you want to call back programmatically, you call Activity.onBackPressed();

Comment: As Max Wong mentioned in his answer, using a `replace()` transaction is equivalent to a `remove()`+`add()` transaction, so it will cause the previous fragments on the relevant tag or id to be immediately removed.

Comment: "when savedInstanceState is not null" - is it when the device is rotated?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Yes, it's when device rotated, or language changed or similar configuration change happens. If you check for null, then you are safe in all that cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling .replace() on the fragment manager it's essentially the same thing as calling .remove().  According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)):

```
This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and 
then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.
```

So you don't need to worry about any further management since it will be taken care of for you (and be removed to free up resources).  This basically means that when one is shown the other is removed.  If you were to call .add() then the fragments would still be alive in the background using up resources but you don't have to worry about that since using .replace() only allows one to live at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need not call any method to destroy the fragments after using them. Android OS will take of them. According to the documentation, When you replace the fragment with another, the **onStop()** method of the fragment will be executed, and documentaed as,

**The fragment is not visible. Either the host activity has been stopped or the fragment has been removed from the activity but added to the back stack. A stopped fragment is still alive (all state and member information is retained by the system). However, it is no longer visible to the user and will be killed if the activity is killed.**

So the fragment will be killed by the OS when the activity is killed. Till the activity is live, fragment objects will reside in the memory.

EDT:

So, if you want to use the fragment again in future, as document suggests,

**Also like an activity, you can retain the state of a fragment using a Bundle, in case the activity's process is killed and you need to restore the fragment state when the activity is recreated. You can save the state during the fragment's onSaveInstanceState() callback and restore it during either onCreate(), onCreateView(), or onActivityCreated(). For more information about saving state, see the Activities document.**

Comment: How can I reuse those residing Fragments then?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the question - it's about _replacing_ (not retaining) the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` are hard coded in `xml` can not replaced....
but when you call `replace(..)` then what happen ?? 
Ok just consider you have 3 fragment **A,B,C** . In primary stage **A** initialize in MainActivity... now you are going to call **B** from **A** using `replace(....)`. that means **A** will go `onPause(),onStop()` state of lifecycle and **B** will be initialized and paced in MainActivity...same as for **C** then **B** is `onPause() ,onStop()` state. If you want to reuse **A** or **B** then you need to call again **A** or **B** from **C** using `replace (..)`. and then **A** or **B** will reinitialize and **C** goes to `onPause(),onStop()`. But there is another way you can do this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
hide(A);
show(B);
ft.commit();
```

if you use above code block then **A** still be in the running state of its lifecycle but not visible (just detached from UI ).. so it would be better if you need those fragment again use `hide()or show()` method because it is **less expensive** operation then reinitialize the fragment.

Comment: In fact, it's better to use the `attach()` and `detach()` transactions instead of `show()` and `hide()` if you wish to retain the fragment instance but remove it from the UI. The former actually removes the UI, while the latter just makes it invisible, and thus retained in memory